# Call an action and prevent closing a Window opened with SwiftUIs @Environment(\.openWindow)

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a SwiftUI App I open a new Window with

```
@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
... 
...
openWindow(value: item.id)
```

```
    WindowGroup("Item", for: Item.ID.self) { $itemId in
      if let id = itemId {
        ItemWindow(persistentID: id)
      }
```

That works fine.

Tree Questions for that window:

- can I prevent, that in the newly created window the top-right red close button is displayed?
- how can I get the NSWindow for that window?
- how can I call some code, if the user tries to close that window with the red button and prevent (in some cases) the closing of the window.

I tried to add a window delegate, but none of the window delegate functions fire, the app delegate functions work fine.

```
@main
struct Window_TestApp: App {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Did Finish launching")
  }
  
  func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    print("applicationShouldTerminate")
    //return .terminateCancel
    return .terminateNow
  }
  
  func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("windowWillClose")
  }
  func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    print("windowShouldClose")
    return true
  }
}
```